# Running MySQL with QuickPHP

Tags: mysql, php

Context: I work at a college and wanted to get students involved in PHP and MySQL development. The IT technicians have configured the systems such that I can’t use packages like XAMPP, USBWebserver or Server2Go. I have tried QuickPHP and that works fine in the environment.

My question is how do I get MySQL running with QuickPHP? I've checked the notes on QuickPHP web but its slightly vague. I downloaded the MySQL Community Edition zip but I am at a loss on what to do next. Bearing in mind I cannot and nor will the students be able to install anything due to restrictive access rights.

Hope that makes sense?

Link to QuickPHP: http://www.zachsaw.com/?pg=quickphp_php_tester_debugger

Comment: Have you tried asking your IT Technicians for a solution. As I'm sure they could provide a separate group of PC's to meet your needs.

Comment: I have to agree with Barry - regardless of the debate ovr what languages you should or shouldn't be teaching (I agree with Tom fwiw) I work in a college myself as a network management type and I'd expect you to be able to count on whoever has that job at your place to help you with this - if you don't have rights to install packages yourself, this is because they *will* so make it their problem... give them a set of requirements and let them solve it. Unless they are fools they'll probably appreciate being asked to help.

Comment: so had a chat, and they wont budge on it. I've read PHP can use MSAccess db. So that seems like a likely option, but when I enable the it in the ini, QUICKPHP says it can't load the dynamic library - any ideas?

Comment: It your IT Technicians won't help you out, take it to the next highest teacher, (Head of Department? and so on up the chain) If you can't teach (aka your job) the curriculum because IT is blocking. Then thats the first problem to solve. Worse case scenario, spend some budget on not IT Technician controlled machines.

Answer (score 4):

Don't.

Be a responsible teacher, and [don't teach them PHP](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/).  There are enough bad PHP programmers in the world without you making more of them.

Teach them something that doesn't suck, like Python, or Ruby.

Instead of having them install a database (which I doubt you'd ever be able to get a portable, non-install MySQL), why not use something like [MongoHQ](https://www.mongohq.com/home), where you've got MongoDB in the cloud.

Alternatively, teach them Javascript, and use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that your entire IDE experience is on the web, this makes it easier for them to do their homework, as they're not reliant on any software that's locally installed.

Comment: can't help if that is what the local universities are delivering in their courses ...

Comment: Then they should provide you with a suitable environment to use for teaching and development.